# Why a simple publish subscribe is not working with zeromq?

Tags: python-3.x, ipc, zeromq, publish-subscribe

I want to establish publish subscribe communication between to machines.

The two machines, that I have, are `ryu-primary` and `ryu-secondary`

The steps I follow in each of the machines are as follows.

In the initializer for `ryu-primary` (IP address is 192.168.241.131)

```
 self.context    = zmq.Context()
 self.sub_socket = self.context.socket(zmq.SUB)
 self.pub_socket = self.context.socket(zmq.PUB)
 self.pub_port   = 5566
 self.sub_port   = 5566


def establish_zmq_connection(self):                      # Socket to talk to server
    print( "Connection to ryu-secondary..." )
    self.sub_socket.connect( "tcp://192.168.241.132:%s" % self.sub_port )

def listen_zmq_connection(self):
    print( 'Listen to zmq connection' )
    self.pub_socket.bind( "tcp://*:%s" % self.pub_port )

def recieve_messages(self):
    while True:
        try:
            string = self.sub_socket.recv( flags=zmq.NOBLOCK )
            print( 'flow mod messages recieved {}'.format(string) )
            return string
        except zmq.ZMQError:
            break

def push_messages(self,msg):
    self.pub_socket.send( "%s" % (msg) )
```

From ryu-secondary (IP address - 192.168.241.132)

In the initializer

```
    self.context    = zmq.Context()
    self.sub_socket = self.context.socket(zmq.SUB)
    self.pub_socket = self.context.socket(zmq.PUB)
    self.pub_port   = 5566
    self.sub_port   = 5566


def establish_zmq_connection(self):                     # Socket to talk to server
     print( "Connection to ryu-secondary..." )
     self.sub_socket.connect( "tcp://192.168.241.131:%s" % self.sub_port )

def listen_zmq_connection(self):
     print( 'Listen to zmq connection' )
     self.pub_socket.bind( "tcp://*:%s" % self.pub_port )

def recieve_messages(self):
    while True:
        try:
            string = self.sub_socket.recv( flags=zmq.NOBLOCK )
            print( 'flow mod messages recieved {}'.format(string) )
            return string
        except zmq.ZMQError:
            break

def push_messages(self,msg):
    print( 'pushing message to publish socket' )
    self.pub_socket.send( "%s" % (msg) )
```

These are the functions that I have.

I am calling on `ryu-secondary`:

```
establish_zmq_connections()
push_messages()
```

But I am **not recieving** those messages on `ryu-primary`, when I call

```
listen_zmq_connection()
recieve_messages()
```

Can someone **point out** to me **what I am doing wrong?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Repair the `PUB/SUB` messaging pattern setup

There are several important steps in making the `PUB/SUB` pattern work.

All this is well described in the ZeroMQ documentation.

You need not repeat both pub & sub parts of code on both sides, the more that it masks, as A side-effect thereof, the case if you mix the pub and sub socket addresses/ports/calls/etc in an "opposite" node code and you do not see such a principal collision.

1. your code defines the initial form of `PUB`-archetype, that is expected to `.push_messages()`
2. your code defines the initial form of `SUB`-archetype, that is expected to `.receive_messages()`
3. your code does **not** show, how do you control who goes first on a connection setup -- whether `.bind()` or `.connect()` appears at random or before/after the other
4. your code does **not** show any subscription setup, after the `SUB`-archetype was instantiated. A default value upon a socket instantiation **does need to be modified** via a `.setsockopt( zmq.SUBSCRIBE = '')` method, otherwise there is a prohibitive filter that does not allow any ( yet unsubscribed ) message to pass through and got-output ( "received" ) on the `SUB`-side

---

### Must modify a default SUB-side subscription filter, it is prohibitive

You may have noticed from the ZeroMQ documentation, that until setup otherwise, the sub-side does filter-out all incoming messages.

> http://api.zeromq.org/2-1:zmq-setsockopt

"The ZMQ_SUBSCRIBE option shall establish a new message filter on a ZMQ_SUB socket. **Newly created ZMQ_SUB sockets shall filter out all incoming messages**, therefore you **should** call this option to establish an initial message filter.

An **empty** `option_value` of length zero shall subscribe to **all incoming** messages. A **non-empty** `option_value` shall subscribe to **all messages beginning with** the specified prefix. Multiple filters **may** be attached to a single ZMQ_SUB socket, in which case a message shall be **accepted if it matches at least one** filter."

---

### Class-method pre-configuration of a Context instance possible

There is another possibility for a python code using `pyzmq 13.0+`. There you **may** also setup this via a Context class-method `.setsockopt( zmq.SUBSCRIBE, "" )` et al, **but** such call has to precede the new socket instantiation from a Context-instance pre-configured this way.

Comment: Can you please check this question please http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26332539/zeromq-typeerror-string-indices-must-be-integers-not-str