# zeromq: TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str

Tags: python, ipc, zeromq

I want to establish publish subscribe communication between to machines.

The two machines, that I have, are `ryu-primary` and `ryu-secondary`

The steps I follow in each of the machines are as follows.

In the initializer for `ryu-primary` (IP address is 192.168.241.131)

```
 self.context    = zmq.Context()
 self.sub_socket = self.context.socket(zmq.SUB)
 self.pub_socket = self.context.socket(zmq.PUB)
 self.pub_port   = 5566
 self.sub_port   = 5566


def establish_zmq_connection(self):                      # Socket to talk to server
    print( "Connection to ryu-secondary..." )
    self.sub_socket.connect( "tcp://192.168.241.132:%s" % self.sub_port )

def listen_zmq_connection(self):
    print( 'Listen to zmq connection' )
    self.pub_socket.bind( "tcp://*:%s" % self.pub_port )

def recieve_messages(self):
    while True:
        try:
            string = self.sub_socket.recv( flags=zmq.NOBLOCK )
            print( 'flow mod messages recieved {}'.format(string) )
            return string
        except zmq.ZMQError:
            break

def push_messages(self,msg):
    self.pub_socket.send( "%s" % (msg) )
```

From ryu-secondary (IP address - 192.168.241.132)

In the initializer

```
    self.context    = zmq.Context()
    self.sub_socket = self.context.socket(zmq.SUB)
    self.pub_socket = self.context.socket(zmq.PUB)
    self.pub_port   = 5566
    self.sub_port   = 5566


def establish_zmq_connection(self):                     # Socket to talk to server
     print( "Connection to ryu-secondary..." )
     self.sub_socket.connect( "tcp://192.168.241.131:%s" % self.sub_port )

def listen_zmq_connection(self):
     print( 'Listen to zmq connection' )
     self.pub_socket.bind( "tcp://*:%s" % self.pub_port )

def recieve_messages(self):
    while True:
        try:
            string = self.sub_socket.recv( flags=zmq.NOBLOCK )
            print( 'flow mod messages recieved {}'.format(string) )
            return string
        except zmq.ZMQError:
            break

def push_messages(self,msg):
    print( 'pushing message to publish socket' )
    self.pub_socket.send( "%s" % (msg) )
```

These are the functions that I have.

I am calling on `ryu-secondary`:

```
establish_zmq_connections()
push_messages()
```

On `ryu-primary`, when I call

```
listen_zmq_connection()
recieve_messages()
```

**after** subscribing to all types of messages using **`.setsockopt( zmq.SUBSCRIBE = '')`**

However the message I am trying to send is of the following type.

```
msg = {'in_port':in_port,'dst':dst,'actions':actions}
self.push_messages(msg)
```

However on the other side (`recieve_messages()` I get the following error when I do this

```
flow_mod = recieve_messages() 

flow_mod['in_port']
flow_mod['dst']
flow_mod['actions']


TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str
```

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser - I want to access the information contained in that dictionary namely the values of the keys 'in_port','dst' and 'actions'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`msg` is a Python dict, but you are sending (and receiving) messages formatted as strings. Probably the easiest thing to do is to serialize `msg` to JSON format, send it as a string, then load the received string back into a dict again. Then, and only then, will you be able to access the keys and values properly. Something like this should work (make sure you `import json` somewhere above):

```
# on the sending end
msg = {'in_port':in_port,'dst':dst,'actions':actions}
msg_string = json.dumps(msg)
self.push_messages(msg)

# on the receiving end
payload = receive_messages()
message = json.loads(payload)
```

You can find the full docs for the `json` module [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) (for Python 2) and [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) for Python 3.

Comment: thanks for the reply.Can you please explain how to do that.I am not very proficient in python?

Answer (score 0):

### ZeroMQ API background

ZeroMQ **`.send()`** **`.recv()`** methods operate on strings. You pass to them a dictionary object they do not know how to process. Transform dictionary object to a JSON-format, as an example of a serialisation aimed to this very situation and your job is done.

### The answer = What is the reason for getting a TypeError?

As writen, the ZeroMQ's `.send()` method could not do much about sending an object it does not understand and the .recv() part still reads whatever gets delivered on the ZeroMQ layer.

Thus your **`flow_mod`** variable, correctly, receives a **string** as **`return string`** instruction in the function **`recieve_messages()`** orders.

The **`string = self.sub_socket.recv( flags=zmq.NOBLOCK )`** simply serves any string, being it an empty one or any non-zero-length string as received from opposite side of the socket.

**Finally:**
The **`flow_mod['in_port']`** will syntactically crash ( and must do so ), because the content of the variable `flow_mod`, assigned & type-adjusted right before this, has no dictionary-alike access method to handle this type of syntax.

Thus the **`TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str`** exception must be raised here.

**Q.E.D.**

---

### JSON serialised representation of objects - Encoding & Decoding intro:

```
>>> import json
>>> print json.__doc__
JSON (JavaScript Object Notation) <http://json.org> is a subset of
JavaScript syntax (ECMA-262 3rd edition) used as a lightweight data
interchange format.

[json] exposes an API familiar to users of the standard library
[marshal] and [pickle] modules. It is the externally maintained
version of the [json] library contained in Python 2.6, but maintains
compatibility with Python 2.4 and Python 2.5 and (currently) has
significant performance advantages, even without using the optional C
extension for speedups.

Encoding basic Python object hierarchies::

    >>> import json
    >>> json.dumps(['foo', {'bar': ('baz', None, 1.0, 2)}])
    '["foo", {"bar": ["baz", null, 1.0, 2]}]'
    >>> print json.dumps("\"foo\bar")
    "\"foo\bar"
    >>> print json.dumps(u'\u1234')
    "\u1234"
    >>> print json.dumps('\\')
    "\\"
    >>> print json.dumps({"c": 0, "b": 0, "a": 0}, sort_keys=True)
    {"a": 0, "b": 0, "c": 0}
    >>> from StringIO import StringIO
    >>> io = StringIO()
    >>> json.dump(['streaming API'], io)
    >>> io.getvalue()
    '["streaming API"]'

Compact encoding::

    >>> import json
    >>> json.dumps([1,2,3,{'4': 5, '6': 7}], sort_keys=True, separators=(',',':'))
    '[1,2,3,{"4":5,"6":7}]'

Pretty printing::

    >>> import json
    >>> print json.dumps({'4': 5, '6': 7}, sort_keys=True,
    ...                  indent=4, separators=(',', ': '))
    {
        "4": 5,
        "6": 7
    }

Decoding JSON::

    >>> import json
    >>> obj = [u'foo', {u'bar': [u'baz', None, 1.0, 2]}]
    >>> json.loads('["foo", {"bar":["baz", null, 1.0, 2]}]') == obj
    True
    >>> json.loads('"\\"foo\\bar"') == u'"foo\x08ar'
    True
    >>> from StringIO import StringIO
    >>> io = StringIO('["streaming API"]')
    >>> json.load(io)[0] == 'streaming API'
    True

Specializing JSON object decoding::

    >>> import json
    >>> def as_complex(dct):
    ...     if '__complex__' in dct:
    ...         return complex(dct['real'], dct['imag'])
    ...     return dct
    ...
    >>> json.loads('{"__complex__": true, "real": 1, "imag": 2}',
    ...     object_hook=as_complex)
    (1+2j)
    >>> from decimal import Decimal
    >>> json.loads('1.1', parse_float=Decimal) == Decimal('1.1')
    True

Specializing JSON object encoding::

    >>> import json
    >>> def encode_complex(obj):
    ...     if isinstance(obj, complex):
    ...         return [obj.real, obj.imag]
    ...     raise TypeError(repr(o) + " is not JSON serializable")
    ...
    >>> json.dumps(2 + 1j, default=encode_complex)
    '[2.0, 1.0]'
    >>> json.JSONEncoder(default=encode_complex).encode(2 + 1j)
    '[2.0, 1.0]'
    >>> ''.join(json.JSONEncoder(default=encode_complex).iterencode(2 + 1j))
    '[2.0, 1.0]'
```

Comment: thanks for the reply.Can you please explain how to do that.I am not very proficient in python?

Comment: I pressed upvote the system downvoted you :( I have reverted it.Will upvote once it works :)